# flutter dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType fails in test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

App runs correctly with `flutter run`

With `flutter drive --target=test_driver/main.dart` the call to dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType returns null

Some relevant code:

```
class TimerServiceProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  const TimerServiceProvider({Key key, this.service, Widget child})
      : super(key: key, child: child);
  final TimerService service;
  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(TimerServiceProvider old) => service != old.service;
}
```

in MyApp the widget tree starts with TimerServiceProvider

```
final timerService = TimerService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TimerServiceProvider(
        // provide timer service to all widgets of your app
        service: timerService,
...
```

on one of the pages

```
timerService = TimerService.of(context);
```

In the function `TimerService.of`, `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` returns `null`.  This works fine during the normal app execution and returns null if run from `flutter driver`.

```
static TimerService of(BuildContext context) {
    var provider =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<TimerServiceProvider>();
    return provider.service;
  }
```

flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: This code is fine. Your issue is likely somewhere else, such as placing `TimerServiceProvider` in `Home`, bu trying to access it in a different route

Comment: The TimerServiceProvider is at the top of the widget tree.  After the main (home) page, all other pages are accessed with Navigator.push

Comment: I'd consider printing your widget tree and your context, and see if your TimerServiceProvider is an ancestor of the context. It's likely the mistake.

Comment: I trying to understand why this would work in the normal `flutter run`, but not with `flutter driver`.

Comment: Your widget tree likely has a different structure.

Comment: with both flutter run and flutter driver, there is a TimerServiceProvider widget at the top of the tree.

Answer (score 2):

Phil, try to set a type for your service.

```
TimerService timerService = TimerService(); //HERE

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TimerServiceProvider(
        // provide timer service to all widgets of your app
        service: timerService,
```

I faced a similar error with my tests, my InheritedWidget has a generic type. My app runs as supposed to, but the tests fail at the same point as yours.